# Ignore URL resolving in third-party CSS files

Tags: webpack

I am using Webpack with the configuration below to compile my CSS. In my CSS I am importing some CSS files from NPM packages - e.g. `@import '../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';` - that contain URLs which it cannot resolve.

Is it possible to disable URL resolving for these imported CSS files specifically? Since I am overwriting these styles anyway with my own CSS I don't need Webpack to handle these.

Example error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{}!./src/css/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ajax-loader.gif' in '/.../css'
@ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{}!./src/css/style.scss 6:9840-9868
@ ./src/css/style.scss
@ ./src/js/app.js
@ multi ./src/js/app.js
```

Excerpt from webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss)$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                minimize: false
            },
        },
        'postcss-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
          }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) is the loader which parses your CSS and resolves URLs and `@import()`s, so you need to make sure that you do not use `css-loader` for any files in your `node_modules` directory. You will need two separate rules:

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader',
  ],
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: /\/node_modules\//,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader',
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably answer from the 9 Jul is working as expected, in 2022 I've used little bit different approach :

```
...
{
  test: /\.css/,
  loaders: [
    'style-loader', {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: { url: false }
    }
  ],
},
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Leave my URLs alone webpack! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to disable sources handling via the class-loaders [url filter function](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader#object). It still seems clunky, but I did not want to add two separate rules.

I ended up with the following css-loader config. This implies that all scss `url()` statements contain the webpack alias `@assets`. Another benefit is that the image url is correctly resolved in the final css output.

```scss
/* main.scss */
.sample-class {
  background: url('@assets/compass.svg');
}
```

```js
// sample alias in webpackConfig
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'assets')
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// css-loader rule in webpackConfig.module.rules
{
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    url: {
      filter: (url) => {
        if (url.startsWith('@assets')) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: my original answer using webpackIgnore comments in scss files did not work, as the imported file was not compiled by the sass compiler.